# How to fix: Having problems with the resulting array of a for-loop equation

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop

I have the following for-loop:

```
T = 100
mu = 10
var = 3
e = np.array(np.random.normal(mu, var, T+1))

yt = np.array([10])
for i in range(1,T+1):
    ythat = 10 + (0.5 * (yt[i-1] - 10)) + e
    yt = np.append(yt,ythat)

len(yt)
```

The result of len(yt) is 10101, however I am only trying to append the numpy array with 100 iterations of the loop.

Note: My goal with the 'yt[i-1]' in the middle is to get the result of the previous iteration of the 'ythat' formula.

Comment: `np.append` is just a cover function for `np.concatenate`.  Both make a new array.  Initializing a correct initial `yt` is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `list` as calling `append` on a numpy array will not always give you what you expect but is also pretty computationally expensive. Change your code to:

```
T = 100
mu = 10
var = 3
e = np.array(np.random.normal(mu, var, T+1))

yt = [10]
for i in range(1,T+1):
    ythat = 10 + (0.5 * (yt[i-1] - 10)) + e
    yt.append(ythat)

len(yt)
```

Note that `yt` cannot be converted to a numpy array as the dimensions do not match for all of its elements.

Comment: Why `10 + e` instead of just `10`?

Comment: @Barmar He won't be able to convert it into a numpy array with 10 being the first value. Also, it doesn't make sense with the rest of the values. I believe he was just using it as a starting point. But that can be changed easily.

Comment: I do actually require, 10 alone to be the starting value. What is the significance of including the e?

Comment: @MrFizz that line can just be changed to `yt = [10]` as shown then. The `10+e` was just because `10 + (0.5 * (yt[i-1] - 10)) + e` with `yt[i-1] == 10` is equivalent to `10+e`. It also allowed `yt` to be converted to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the axis to append on. Without an axis, `np.append()` will flatten the arrays and concatenate them. To add a new row to the array, use

```
yt = np.append(yt, ythat, axis=0)
```

You also need to make the original `yt` array 2-dimensional:

```
yt = np.array([10 + e])
```

Comment: This gives `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions` unless the first values is changed to `10+e`

Comment: Does my addition fix it?

Comment: What is the significance of including the e? I do require 10 alone to be the starting value. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Maybe it should be `yt = np.array([10] * T)`?

Comment: Or `yt = np.array([[10] * T])`